# Excel VBA - Assign Folder Path to Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a folder path as a string so that I can reference that path later. Below is some of the code that leads up to that folder path.

```
Dim fzp as String
Dim fPath As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim subFold

fPath = "I:\PROJECTS\" & ProjNam & "\" & ProjNum
fso.createfolder (fPath & "copy")
fso.CopyFolder "S:\Global\Specifications\Proposal Packages\" & ProjNum & "*", fPath & "copy\"
With fso
Set subFold = .getfolder(fPath & "copy")
Set subFold = subFold.Subfolders
```

Now when I look in the local window I see `subFold` with `Item(1)` with a Path of "I:\PROJECTS\Foo\bar\Subfoldername"

I want that entire pathway and so I've tried:

```
fzp = subFold.Path
fzp = subFold.Item(1).Path
fzp = .Item(1).Path
fzp = .Path
```

and probably 20 different iterations without success.

Any idea how I can assign that folder path to a string value or reference it correctly?

Comment: Are you looking for `subFold(1).Path`? The `.Subfolders` property returns an array containing all the subfolders in that folder; you're setting your `subFold` variable equal to that array.

Comment: @JoshEller I want the variable fzp to be equal to the file path as shown for subfolder.item(1).